# jquery response need outside variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to know how to get ajax variable outside of the ajax request ?
Is it possible to do something like with below code?
I know there is much more easier way to do achieve this but how can i achieve with below code?

```
var response = null;
        var gn = {
            type: 'POST',
            data: datasubmited,
            url: "http://localhost/test/abc/def",
            success:function(data){
                try {
                    data = $.parseJSON(data);
                    response=data;
                    console.log(response.Name); // i can see value here
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
                console.log(response.Name); // i can see value here as well.
            },
            error: self.request_error,
            complete: self.submit_to_server_ok
        }
        $.ajax(gn);
        console.log(response.Name); //Right now showing here response is NULL.But want to see response.Name value here.
```

Comment: The **A**JAX request is **asynchronous**, therefore `response` is still null when you're attempting to use it. For this to work you need to put the `console.log` *inside* the `success` handler

Comment: I think i have already put console.log inside the success handler.

Comment: Then you already have your solution :)